# Get the MD5 hash code (as a String) for a given file in C#

Tags: java, c#

How can I get the MD5 hash code (as a String) for a given file in C#?
I know how to do it in Java, but can anyone tell me how to do this in C#?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not translation service.

Comment: Please try something and if you have any problems you can ask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also don't get your hopes up about the code, **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Comment: We don't do your work for you in this site, you sit down, do the work and come here with specific questions on specific problems you encounter, if you want a "do it for me" service, go to other sites and pay for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgot to state the correct question. As I can see from the Java code provided (*reverse engineering*), all you want is to have *MD5 hash code* (as a *String*) for a given *file*; if it's your case, you want just to

1. Create MD5 crypto
2. Open the file
3. Compute hash on file stream
4. Represent hash (which is `Byte[]`) as `String`.

The implementation could be

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
//TODO: it's very time to rename "sig" into something more readable
private static String sig(String fileName) {
  using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create()) {
    using (FileStream stm = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
      return String.Concat(md5Hash
        .ComputeHash(stm)
        .Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do that the next time!